# Creating s3 bucket with lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wrote this lambda function for creating new s3 bucket. I got success response, but there is no bucket created:

```
//Creating new s3 bucket 
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    region: '',
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
  });
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var bucketName = 'sample_bucket'; 
var keyName = 'sample_text.txt';


exports.handler = function uploadToS3(event, context, callback) {
  s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucketName, 
    Key: keyName, 
    Body: 'Hello World!'
  };

  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName);
  });
});
  callback(null,{ result : 'SUCCESS'});
};
```

Is there any problem in the code or do I have to provide some special access to 
IAM user? I provided programmatic access to the IAM user.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you try to access the new S3 Bucket?

Comment: I couldn't access the new bucket because it wasn't created, it's not appear in my s3 bucket list

Comment: Could be name was taken, or IAM user didn't have s3 access, check the cloudwatch logs of the lambda function for the responses of the s3 functions.

Comment: Thanks guys, I successfully created the lambda, I just had to change the role to full access.